# undefined number after removing special characters javascript

Tags: javascript

The string - USD 255,012
I only just need numbers 255012
I am using a method  getNumbers(str) to remove the text USD and , or any dot .

Function is getting fine but return value from function is NAN.

I am using this method

```
function getNumbers(str)
{
  return parseInt(str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")); // it will get only numbers.
}
```

Whenever I use above method

```
 var piInput = getNumbers( 1,50.00 );
```

return value in variable piInput  is undefined type why is that?

my jsfiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/c0x7wko3/

not sure why it is not showing the result.

My method detecting type of variable.

```
   function getTypeofVariable( msg ,  myvar ) {

    if ( typeof myvar === 'string' )
    {
        alert(msg + myvar + " is STRING type vairable " );
    }
    if ( typeof myvar === 'number' )
    {
        alert(msg + myvar + " is number type vairable " );
    }
    if ( typeof myvar === 'boolean' )
    {
        alert(msg + myvar + " is boolean type vairable " );
    }
        if ( typeof myvar === 'symbol' )
    {
        alert(msg + myvar + " is symbol type vairable " );
    }
        if ( typeof myvar === 'object' )
    {
        alert(msg + myvar + " is object type vairable " );
    }
        if ( typeof myvar === 'undefined' )
    {
        alert(msg + myvar + " is undefined type vairable " );
    }

    if ( typeof myvar === 'number' )
    {
        alert(msg + myvar + " is number type vairable " );
    }
}
```

Comment: pass a string: `var piInput = getNumbers( "1,50.00" );` - but what you have posted would not return `undefined` rather it would error as there is no `Number.replace()`

Comment: First of all, you give `getNumbers` 2 parameter (1 and 500) second, you try to apply string replace on a integer, I think you should look at that first

Comment: You could also use `\D` which means "not digit" : `.replace(/\D/g, "")`

Comment: @AlexK. now I understand that i need to post a string variable but how about this   var sitdDigitsOnly = getNumbers( $(this).text() );  How I can tackle with this ?

Comment: @JeremyThille I need digits only from string

Comment: @Peter You mean to make sure it is a string?

Comment: @Peter what do you mean, "I need digits only from string"? And what in my comment is not relevant with that?

Comment: Make the fiddle repeat the behaviour you see, .text() should not return undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass string to getNumbers and there is also some syntax errors please check out that too:

```
function getNumbers(str)
{
    return (str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")); 
}

var piInput = getNumbers( "1,50.00" );
alert(piInput);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply 

var sitdDigitsOnly = getNumbers(  $(this).text()  );
How I can make it as a string?

Comment: var n = sitdDigitsOnly.toString();

Comment: @Peter if this answer is really helpful for you make mark as a right so other can get it easily.

Comment: No luck here is the code 

var sii = $(this).find("input").val();
var salesInoiceInput =  getNumbers( sii.toString() );

Comment: don't do like that see this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for your help.